# How do I Load a Partial View and Fetch Json Data with an API

Tags: jquery, json, single-page-application

I am creating a single page application and i need expert advice on which to load first, the view or the json data via rest api? The app is full out SPA with the data in each view being constantly refreshed on intervals. My problem is, i want to try to merge the json data with the view as quick possible without any lag to the user and a beautiful user experience. So do i fetch the the API data before the view, or the view before the data??

Comment: Try both and see which is better. JSON you would need to fetch many times but the html, once should be enough because it wont change

Comment: @CodingYoshi so are u saying since i am gonna fetch the view once, i should fetch it first, then .call the Json data Apis on intervals for that view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want there to be no visual lag, I suggest fetching the data first, then the view. This way, when your view arrives, the data is already there and ready to be merged in.